# Можно ли так расставить запятые?

Tags: пунктуация, стилистика

Об него-то спотыкались и матерились падая братья по разуму.

Мне необходимо расставить акценты так, чтобы при чтении они делили предложение на три части: "Об него-то спотыкались. И матерились падая. Братья по разуму". Это принципиально.
Могу ли я расставить их так:
"Об него-то спотыкались, и матерились падая, братья по разуму".

Тварь ли я дрожащая или право имею?

Comment: Пр такой пунктуации и порядки слов получится такой смысл: что падали во время того, как матерились. Лучше исправить предложение.

Comment: Об него-то спотыкались, и, падая, матерились  братья по разуму.

Comment: От такой перестановки изменяется "настроение" предложения. Эмоциональная окраска. А мне очень хочется её сохранить. Само выражение: "И матерились, падая...", содержит в себе что-то такое... вкусное. Плавное. А переставь слова и получится обычный интернет-язык.

Comment: Если бы вы так хорошо чувствовали язык, то вы не задали этот вопрос здесь. То, о чем вы говорите, ни на чем не основанное утверждение.

Comment: То есть - "так же хорошо как вы"? Я чувствую в вашем предложении пропущенное слово. :)

Answer (score 1):

Для деления на три части нужна вставка:

Об него-то спотыкались - и матерились падая - братья по разуму.

Comment: Вставку тоже можно выделить запятыми. Хотя почему вы здесь предлагаете вставку - не пойму.

Comment: Лопатин говорит: "Вставные конструкции (слова, сочетания слов, предложения) выделяются скобками или тире". Разделить на части, как предлагает автор, может только вставка. Про предложенный вариант с запятыми скажут, что это неправильная пунктуация, а правильно:Об него-то спотыкались и матерились, падая, братья по разуму.

Comment: А чёрточка что тут делает?

Comment: Согласно Розенталю вставные конструкции могут выделяться запятыми.

Comment: Запятыми обособляются вводные предложения,  а у вставки интонация исключительная: общий пониженный тон, изменение темпа речи. Это только с помощью тире можно обозначить, но оно вас  почему-то не устраивает. А по-моему - очень неплохо смотрится, оригинальной идее требуется оригинальное оформление.

Comment: Вообще-то, тире я люблю. Когда-то прочитал, что тире очень любила Агата Кристи, и даже им злоупотребляла. И именно это сделало её книги популярными (наверно шутка автора статьи ;) ).   Но к варианту с тире: "Об него-то и спотыкались - и матерились, падая - братья по разуму." мне надо привыкнуть, покатать во рту. Пока, на взгляд, выглядит диковато (лично для меня).

Comment: Решайтесь! (Тварь ли я дрожащая или право имею?). Другим способом  вашу задачу не выполнить, а вставные конструкции могут иметь любой вид, так что правила формально не нарушаются. Кстати, деепричастие можно не обособлять - чего уж там! - так эффектнее смотрится. Будем считать, что оно выполняет функцию обстоятельства (матерились при падении). А вообще говоря, русская пунктуация очень пластична и вполне позволяет автору выражать свои замыслы. Пусть содержание управляет формой, а не наоборот.

Comment: . В редких случаях вставная конструкция выделяется запятыми: Мне показалось даже, а может быть оно и в самом деле было так, что все стали к нам ласковее (Акс.); Экспонаты Биологического музея, а их свыше двух тысяч, рассказывают о животном мире нашей планеты (Газ.). Розенталь.

Comment: Обратите внимание на союзы, в этом случае не требуется такой сильный знак, как тире.

Comment: И что? В примере автора нет союзов? Да и к тому же, вставка содержит дополнительные сведения, замечания, уточнения, пояснения, поправки к сказанному; разъясняют, толкуют основную часть высказывания. В нашем примере нет ничего подобного.

Comment: Согласен, Sibylla, так пойдет. Более того, думаю, что другим способом тут и не выкрутишься, больно уж своеобразна цель. Что же касается идеи  "в редких случаях выделяется запятыми", то, во-первых, это нехарактерно для современного стиля, а во-вторых возможно тогда, когда запятые эти наглядно выделяют обособляемую часть, т.е. ставятся в силу естественного понимания структуры фразы, а не вопреки ему, как в нашем случае, где нужно нужно передать отнюдь не естественное членение, а весьма своеобразное. В жизни не догадаешься что у автора между запятыми стоит некая "обособляемая" часть.

Comment: Спасибо за понимание, очень ценю Вашу поддержку.

Comment: И для Сержа: Да, союзы есть, да не те. Это искусственное деление текста на три части согласно замыслу автора. Ему захотелось вычленить и выделить центральную часть, и замысел неплохой, получилось весьма эффектно. Такой новый прием, для которого трудно найти похожих примеров, так как это поиск нестандартных форм. И правилами он не запрещен, вставка - свободная  конструкция, ее можно наполнить любым содержанием. Ну почему автор должен обязательно писать  в формате правил Лопатина/Розенталя, хочется прочитать что-нибудь яркое, необычное.

Comment: *Спасибо за понимание, очень ценю Вашу поддержку*  - Да не за что. Только учтите, что в моем понимании поддержка не должна выходить за рамки обычной помощи новичку. А дальше не должно быть (в идеале) ни групповщины, ни какой-то конкуренции, даже соревновательность тут какая-то особо не нужна. Так что повода поддерживать кого-то лично у меня нет. ))) Удачи!

Comment: @Sibylla  А может быть просто сделать двусоставное предложение? Как вы посмотрите на такой вариант: "Об него-то и спотыкались. И матерились падая, братья по разуму." В принципе, "торжественный" стиль сохраняется. И читается так, как я задумал.

Comment: Нет, этот вариант мне не нравится: такое членение  не имеет смысла. При использовании тире мы имеем основное сообщение: "Об него-то и спотыкались братья по разуму", а вставка в виде дополнительной информации эффектно выделена, придает тексту интересную объемность. Во втором варианте ничего этого нет, да и задуманного деления на три части тоже нет.

Answer (score 0):

Вот Лермонтов и Бунин, Чехов и Толстой, Александра Маринина и Дарья Донцова как-то ухитрялись (а некоторые и сейчас ухитряются) расставлять акценты, не надругиваясь (sic!) над пунктуацией. Оно ж в том и искусство...

Comment: «Мне необходимо расставить акценты», — просит romandc.

Comment: Вряд ли все они так уж и обходились. :) Вот, насчёт Лермонтова - http://arzamas.academy/materials/116  У каждого писателя найдётся собственный "грешок", теперь воспринимаемый как "достижение", "бунт против системы" и пр. и др.   Но самый главный вопрос: "Мы для пунктуации или пунктуация для нас?"  Не стоит ли самым главным показателем грамотности считать понятность текста, и то, что именно хотел выразить автор?

Comment: >> *Но самый главный вопрос: "Мы для пунктуации или пунктуация для нас?"* Не "самый главный", а чисто риторический. Мы для математики или математика для нас? Давайте плюнем на эту совершенно ненужную строгость и будем по наитию — от балды... *Не стоит ли самым главным показателем грамотности считать понятность текста, и то, что именно хотел выразить автор?* Стоит. Именно для этого грамматика и существует. Не только для этого, но в основном... Но главное: если вам вдруг показалось, что для понятности вашего текста требуется перекувырнуть грамматику, то подумайте еще сто раз — и измените текст.

Comment: >> *«Мне необходимо расставить акценты», — просит romandc.* И что? Мне необходимо самовыразиться, можно ли мне на автомагистрали ездить задом?

Comment: "можно ли мне на автомагистрали ездить задом?"              Законы физики этому не препятствуют. :)  Так, что - можно. Этому препятствуют только ПДД.

Comment: Только вчера спорил - как должен читаться текст - как задумал автор, или так, как привык читать читатель? :) Я за право автора преподносить читателю текст так, как он считает нужным! Главное, чтобы читатель понял, что именно до него хотят донести. Главное - не считать правила русского языка чем-то незыблемым. Русский язык уникален и неповторим! У него свои правила жизни, он умеет самоочищаться, в этом я согласен с Успенским.

Comment: Вот именно. В грамматике тоже есть свои ПДД.

Comment: "Умеет самоочищаться" – забавный аргумент. Зачем же заставлять его это делать? Река тоже умеет самоочищаться – давайте бросать в нее всякую дрянь?

Comment: *Не стоит ли самым главным показателем грамотности считать понятность текста, и то, что именно хотел выразить автор?* - Соответвие одного другому вполне можно считать одним из показателей. Если текст большинством читателей именно так, как задумывал и выразил - с помощью орфографии и особенно пунктуации - автор, то да, автор достаточно грамотен.

Comment: А вот по отдельности - как-то не очень. Сама по себе понятность текста, тем более - оценка того, что он **хотел** выразить, - это уже отдельный разговор, далекий от собственно грамотности.

Answer (score 0):

> Могу ли я расставить их так: "Об него-то спотыкались, и матерились
>   падая, братья по разуму".

Нет, так не получится. Первая запятая здесь совершенно невозможна, сказуемые здесь однородны и соединены союзом И, это исключает запятую как знак для перечисления. А никакой другой мотивации для запятой тут нет. Кроме "очень хочется для разбивки на три части", но этого мало.

Вот, пожалуй, вставкой, как это предлагает Sibylla, - пойдет. Другого не вижу.

Comment: И к вам тот же вопрос - возможен ли такой вариант: "Об него-то и спотыкались. И матерились падая, братья по разуму."

Comment: @romandc Возможен, а почему нет? Грамматически. Но он вряд ли устроит автора стилистически, да и вопрос заданный не предполагает ответа в виде расчленения фразы на два (и более) самостоятельных предложения. Это было бы слишком просто и очевидно.

Comment: [/sarcasm] ? :) Автор задаёт вопросы не с целью поднять бучу на ресурсе. И не с целью троллинга. Автор мучается собственной безграмотностью. И собственной глупостью и физической неспособностью запоминать правила. "Не бричка мучает попа...". Нативная расстановка знаков препинания автором, в конце-концов, обнаруживает его полную тупость. Автор не вылезает из инет-справочников, кажется в сотый раз проверяя пунктуацию слова "кажется". В общем - трудно копать ложкой подземный ход. :) Но надо.

Comment: @romandc, постарайтесь писать более содержательные комментарии по обсуждаемому вопросу. Пока я не вижу необходимости что-то Вам отвечать по Вами понаписанному. По вопросу рытья ложкой подземных ходов вы можете обратиться на сайт ближайшего инжнерного-строительного учреждения.